# Buscar textos na DB sem '</ br>'

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, ascii

Estou a trabalhar num CMS que faça edição de textos já na base de dados, este funciona da seguinte forma: existem uma série de `inputs[type="radio"]` cada um deles é um projeto, e quando um deles é clickado aparecem 4 `textareas` (via Ajax) com os quatro textos correspondentes a esse projecto. O meu problema é que nos textos aparecem os `</ br>` inseridos anteriormente com a função `nl2br` de PHP, isso é um problema porque quem vai editar os textos não precisa ver isso. Eu tenho o seguinte código:

editForm.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['editTexts'])) {
        if (!empty($_POST['projectIdToEditTexts'])) {

            $id = $_POST['projectIdToEditTexts'];
            $textSeveralToEdit  = nl2br(trim(htmlentities(ucfirst($_POST['editTextSeveral']))));
            $extraTextToEdit  = nl2br(trim(htmlentities(ucfirst($_POST['editExtraTextSeveral']))));
            $textSeveralPTToEdit  = nl2br(trim(htmlentities(ucfirst($_POST['editTextSeveralPT']))));
            $extraTextPTToEdit  = nl2br(trim(htmlentities(ucfirst($_POST['editExtraTextSeveralPT']))));


            $dataBase->updateTextsEdit($id, $textSeveralToEdit, $extraTextToEdit, $textSeveralPTToEdit, $extraTextPTToEdit);
            echo '<p style="text-align:center; color:green;">Success!!<br><br>Text updated!!</p>';

        }
        else {
            echo '<p style="color:red; text-align:center">You must choose a project where to edit the Texts!!</p>';
        }
    }
    ?>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <h2>Edit texts from project</h2>
            Select the project you want to edit:
            <br>
            <?php
            foreach ($dataBase->fetchAllProjectsAdmin() as $EditButton) {
            ?>
                <input class="radioEditTexts" type="radio" name="projectIdToEditTexts" value="<?php echo $EditButton->id; ?>">
            <?php
            echo '<h4>' .$EditButton->description. '</h4>';
            } ?>
            <br>
            <div id="editTexts">

            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="editTexts">
        </form>

......

$('.radioEditTexts').click(function() {

            var viewTexts = $(this).attr('value');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '../Ajax/editTexts.php',
                data: {"idProject":viewTexts},
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#editTexts').stop().html(data).hide().fadeIn(500);
                }
            });
        });
```

editTexts.php

```
$projectId = $_GET['idProject'];

$getTexts = $dataBase->getDetailsById($projectId)[0];

$mainTextEN = $getTexts->text_several;
$extraTextEN = $getTexts->extra_text;
$mainTextPT = $getTexts->text_severalPT;
$extraTextPT = $getTexts->extra_textPT;

?>
<label>Main Text (PT)?<br><br>
    <textarea name="editTextSeveralPT" cols="50" rows="5"><?php echo $mainTextPT; ?></textarea>
</label>
<br>
<br>
<label>Extra text (PT)?<br><br>
    <textarea name="editExtraTextSeveralPT" cols="50" rows="5"><?php echo $extraTextPT; ?></textarea>
</label>
<br>
<br>
<label>Main Text?<br><br>
    <textarea name="editTextSeveral" cols="50" rows="5"><?php echo $mainTextEN; ?></textarea>
</label>
<br>
<br>
<label>Extra text?<br><br>
    <textarea name="editExtraTextSeveral" cols="50" rows="5"><?php echo $extraTextEN; ?></textarea>
</label>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assumindo que eu tenha entendido corretamente, basta reverter aquilo que a função nl2br() faz.

Como não existe algo nativo, basta uma substituição simples:

```
$var = str_replace( array( '<br>', '<br/>', '<br />' ), "\n", $var );
```

Ou uma regular, que é mais curta. Tanto faz:

```
$var = preg_replace( '#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $var );
```

Um exemplo mais completo:

```
<textarea name="editExtraTextSeveralPT" cols="50" rows="5"><?php echo str_replace( array( '<br>', '<br/>', '<br />' ), "\n", $extraTextPT ); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Obgado, mas eu não quero retirar os '</ br>' quero apenas que eles não sejam mostrados no formulário de edição, queria apenas que muda-se de linha.

Comment: ex: http://www.lisaportugal.pt/Ao_Ritmo_Da_Produ%C3%87%C3%83o. Caso queira mudar texto por baixo do video não gostava que na 'textarea' onde fosse editar aparece-se os '</ br>', apenas mudar de linha.  Não quero excluir a hipótese de o user mudar de linha (nl2r).

Comment: Isso é apenas um auxílio visual. Sim, você estará removendo os `<br />` de dentro dos TEXTAREAS, mas no lugar deles entrarão quebras de linha (\n). Quando o formulário for submetido para edição, contanto que você tenha outro nl2br() igual na rotina que processa a inclusão de um campo novo, no banco de dados os `<br />` vão continuar presentes.

Comment: Ha desculpe sim, falei sem pensar... Entendi, correto esse seria o comportamento esperado no entanto: http://iwanttobesanta.com/hey.png. Não percebo o porquê. Também já tentei com 'preg_replace'

Comment: Se você se refer ao "Extra text", não. Veja que você optou pelo str_replace() mas removeu os `<br />`. Você de substituí-las por uma quebra de linha (\n) senão ao processar esse formulário nl2br(0 não terá com o que trabalhar. Além de fazer o texto ficar visualmente todo grudado dentro do TEXTAREA.

Comment: Perfeito, peço desculpa pela minha precipitação

Comment: Sem problemas, que bom que pude ajudar :)

Comment: Uns `<br>` no seu código seriam bem-vindos ;) http://i.stack.imgur.com/HtMzz.png @Bruno

Comment: Como assim, @brasofilo?

Comment: Editei a resposta pra demonstrar, é legal tentar evitar a barra de rolagem horizontal (no meu snapshot mostra o plugin que uso pra expandir código com barra de rolagem). Mas isso não é parte de [nenhuma normativa de formatação](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas), fique a vontade pra reverter. . . . mas acho que vou colocar a sugestão lá no guia...

Comment: Entendi, mas nesse caso em particular eu vou sim reverter unicamente por se tratar de um TEXTAREA que mantém os espaços de indentação como parte do conteúdo. Na verdade eu até havia escrito dessa forma, indentado, e mudei depois.

Answer (score 1):

Já tive esse problema e resolvi de outra forma, ao invés de salvar com nl2br e toda vez ter q reverter para editar e depois aplicar dinovo para salvar, resolvi salvar com \n mesmo no banco e usar o nl2br somente quando o usuário fosse ler o texto de fato. Poupei trabalho e espaço no banco no caso de textos muito grandes com muitas quebras de linha.